# How monitor Contentful API usage?

Tags: contentful, contentful-management

Is it possible to monitor how many Contentful API calls are being made, and ideally receive a notification when a quota is about to be exceeded?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can check API usage under user profile's dropdown on the right > `Organizations and Billing` > `Subscriptions` page. Also, if you switch to `Spaces` tab, you'll find Contentful Delivery API usage per space.

Comment: no problem :) feel free to ping me if you need any further assistance.